# Removing duplicates in a vector of strings

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of strings:

```
std::vector<std::string> fName
```

which holds a list of file names `<a,b,c,d,a,e,e,d,b>`.

I want to get rid of all the files that have duplicates and want to retain only the files that do not have duplicates in the vector.

```
for(size_t l = 0; l < fName.size(); l++)
{
    strFile = fName.at(l);
    for(size_t k = 1; k < fName.size(); k++)
    {
        strFile2 = fName.at(k);
        if(strFile.compare(strFile2) == 0)
        {
            fName.erase(fName.begin() + l);
            fName.erase(fName.begin() + k);
        }
    }
}
```

This is removing a few of the duplicate but still has a few duplicates left, need help in debugging.

Also my input looks like `<a,b,c,d,e,e,d,c,a>` and my expected output is `<b>` as all other files b,c,d,e have duplicates they are removed.

Comment: Do you want to keep any copy of the duplicates? I.e. do you want <a,b,c,d,e>, or just <c>?

Comment: I dont want to keep the copy of dupilcates.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
void remove_duplicates(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
  std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
  vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());
}
```

Note: this require that T has `operator<` and `operator==` defined.

**Why it work?**

[std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) sort the elements using their less-than comparison operator

[std::unique](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/) removes the duplicate consecutive elements, comparing them using their equal comparison operator

**What if i want only the unique elements?**

Then you better use std::map

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

template <typename T>
void unique_elements(std::vector<T>& vec)
{   
  std::map<T, int> m;
  for(auto p : vec) ++m[p];
  vec.erase(transform_if(m.begin(), m.end(), vec.begin(),
                         [](std::pair<T,int> const& p) {return p.first;},
                         [](std::pair<T,int> const& p) {return p.second==1;}),
            vec.end());
}
```

See: [here](http://ideone.com/HFhmj).

Comment: Also need to include #include <algorithm> for std::sort and std::unique to work.

Comment: Gigi thank you this worked but did not solve my original problem... I started off with <a,b,c,d,e,e,d,b,a> I want my output to be <a> and not <a,b,c,d,e>

Comment: Sorry I want my output to be <c> which is not repeated.

Comment: Your solution using `std::set` does the same thing as your solution using `std::sort/unique`.

Comment: @Gigi Gigi thank you this worked but did not solve my original problem... I started off with <a,b,c,d,e,e,d,b,a> I want my output to be <c> and not <a,b,c,d,e>

Comment: You should just `vec.swap(ret)`, and not copy everything over. Even better, just return the vector. Also, if you really want to copy, simply call `vec = ret;`.

Comment: Have you tested this function?  Does it even compile for you?

Comment: @Gigi: No.  Still wrong. "a" is repeated 4 times in the initial vector, but it still shows up in your output.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Hopefully this one work. No luck without using std::map :(

Comment: @Gigi: Yeah, that works.  That's the answer I gave two hours ago.  Not sure what the purpose of that counter class is though.  Is it just to initialize the int to 0?  `std::map` will do that automatically with an int.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your requirements correctly, and I'm not entirely sure that I do.  You want to only keep the elements in your vector of which do not repeat, correct?

Make a map of strings to ints, used for counting occurrences of each string.  Clear the vector, then copy back only the strings that only occurred once.

```
map<string,int> m;
for (auto & i : v)
    m[i]++;
v.clear();
for (auto & i : m)
    if(i.second == 1)
        v.push_back(i.first);
```

Or, for the compiler-feature challenged:

```
map<string,int> m;
for (vector<string>::iterator i=v.begin(); i!=v.end(); ++i)
    m[*i]++;
v.clear();
for (map<string,int>::iterator i=m.begin(); i!=m.end(); ++i)
    if (i->second == 1)
        v.push_back(i->first);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <algorithms>

template <typename T>
remove_duplicates(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
  std::vector<T> tvec;
  uint32_t size = vec.size();
  for (uint32_t i; i < size; i++) {
    if (std::find(vec.begin() + i + 1, vec.end(), vec[i]) == vector.end()) {
      tvec.push_back(t);
    } else {
      vec.push_back(t);
    }
  vec = tvec; // : )
  }
}
```

Comment: `std::vector` does not have `pop_front()`

Comment: there is only pop_back() could not find a pop_front(). Mr Lindley would be great if you could help. thank you perreal

Comment: @DeepakB: I helped.  Do you not see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate duplicates in O(log n) runtime and O(n) space:

```
std::set<std::string> const uniques(vec.begin(), vec.end());
vec.assign(uniques.begin(), uniques.end());
```

But the O(log n) runtime is a bit misleading, because the O(n) space actually does O(n) dynamic allocations, which are expensive in terms of speed. The elements must also be comparable (here with `operator<()`, which `std::string` supports as a lexicographical compare).

If you want to store only unique elements:

```
template<typename In>
In find_unique(In first, In last)
{
    if( first == last ) return last;
    In tail(first++);
    int dupes = 0;
    while( first != last ) {
        if( *tail++ == *first++ ) ++dupes;
        else if( dupes != 0 ) dupes = 0;
        else return --tail;
    }
    return dupes == 0 ? tail : last;
}
```

The algorithm above takes a sorted range and returns the first unique element, in linear time and constant space. To get all uniques in a container you might use it like so:

```
auto pivot = vec.begin();
for( auto i(find_unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()));
     i != vec.end();
     i = find_unique(++i, vec.end())) {
    std::iter_swap(pivot++, i);
}
vec.erase(pivot, vec.end());
```

Comment: To be frank I'd go with the `std::sort()` and `std::unique()` approach. I just thought I'd show an alternative. :)

Comment: a horrible example in any case (performance, etc), smells like a workaround for those who are lazy enough to not check the algorithm library

Comment: O( log N) runtime is not possible. This is a sorting-problem and as such O( N * log N ) - or if the data is already sorted than O( N ).