# Remove similar items on an object list

Tags: c++

I am populating a `std::list<item*> items`list from a text file, but there are instances where the name variable is the same, in those instances I want to remove the duplicated item (the item with the same name, other information of the item is irrelevant) but get data from that object to add to the 'original' (the first instance of the item)

Because I want to be able to load multiple information, aka an array of sorts into 'items' and this is what I have so far come up with

I tried to loop through items, then loop again and check the first loop against the second loop, copy the information and add to the array of the first loop item but it just breaks.

Suggestions?

Similar to this: [Removing duplicates in a vector of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237216/removing-duplicates-in-a-vector-of-strings)
Except I want to use the information found in any duplicate and add it to a `std::list` that the item object holds

So if I load this:

```
Set Normal DIfficulty|Sets your save game to normal difficulty|/JKSV/Saves/Fire_Emblem__Awakening/hack/Chapter0|0x0D|0x00
Set Normal DIfficulty|Sets your save game to normal difficulty|/JKSV/Saves/Fire_Emblem__Awakening/hack/Chapter0|0x0F|0x0A
Set Hard DIfficulty|Sets your save game to hard difficulty|/JKSV/Saves/Fire_Emblem__Awakening/hack/Chapter0|0x0D|0x01
Set Lunatic DIfficulty|Sets your save game to lunatic difficulty|/JKSV/Saves/Fire_Emblem__Awakening/hack/Chapter0|0x0D|0x02
Set Lunatic+ DIfficulty|Sets your save game to lunatic+ difficulty|/JKSV/Saves/Fire_Emblem__Awakening/hack/Chapter0|0x0D|0x03
```

It will only have 1 `Set Normal Difficulty` item but that item will hold the duplicates last 2 pieces of information (aka `0x0F|0x0A`

Comment: `std::(multi)set`? `std::(multi)map`?

Comment: I am not sure where or how to impliment that, I apologize I am quite new to C++]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your `std::list<T>` to erase duplicate values you have to call `unique` member function. There are two overloads of it. First take 0 arguments and compares values using `operator==`. It is not your case cause your list contains pointers and you don't need to compare addresses but `name` members. So try a second one. It takes a binary predicate where you can compare members

```
std::list<item*> myList;
//   populate your list..

//   sort it before calling unique..
myList.sort([](const item *lhs,const item *rhs)->bool{
    return lhs->name < rhs->name;
});
myList.unique([](const item *lhs,const item *rhs)->bool{
    return lhs->name == rhs->name;
});
//   now your list has no duplicates..
```

More info [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/unique/).

Comment: This does the first part and its pretty sweet, but how could i get the extra info from the duplicate object? (it has 2 longs I want to grab, and add to the original' from the duplicate) So it would be like oriiginal->array.push_back(info_from_duplicate_with_same_name);

Comment: List needs to be sorted before applying `unique()` as the latter only removes consecutive duplicates.

Comment: The first snippet of code worked fine @fnc12, can you apply my first comment? im not sure how to apply it

Comment: BUmping because this still doesnt solve my full question

Comment: @Cacoon hit me in skype `fnc1234` I will help you

Comment: @fnc12 I appreciate the offer but seems I figured it out, was just weird to do, thanks for the help