# How can i erase duplicated elements from a multimap<int, std::pair<int, bool>>?

Tags: c++, containers, multimap

I have a multimap with duplicates. When I finished the collection of the elements i would like to erase the dups.

Here is the container:

```
std::multimap<int, std::pair<int, bool>> container;
```

This following code is inside an iteration.(it is a simpler version of the original)

```
container.emplace(LeafId, std::make_pair(NodeId, isElectronic));
```

Is it good solution?

```
std::pair<int, std::pair<int, bool>> lastValue {-1 , {-1, -1}}; 
    for (auto it = container.cbegin(); it != container.cend();)
    {
        if (it->first == lastValue.first && it->second == lastValue.second)
        {
            it = container.erase(it);
        } else
        {
            lastValue = *it;
            ++it;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can compare `std::pair` with `operator==` you do ot have to write it manually

Comment: like: std::pair<int, std::pair<int, bool>> lastValue {-1 , {-1, -1}};  ?

Comment: Do you mean `std::pair<int, bool>> lastValue{ -1, {-1, -1};`? With `std::map` it would not compile not in `if` not in `lastValue = *it;`, please correct

Comment: Yes. I correct the code.

Comment: would `std::adjacent_find` to find duplicates and then erase them do it for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it good solution?

Unless you keep internal pair sorted inside multimap, no it is not a good solution as it would miss duplicates. If you can change data type then you can use:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<std::pair<int, bool>>>
```

instead of `std::multimap` and then for each element sort vector and remove duplicates using standard algorithms as described here [Removing duplicates in a vector of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237216/removing-duplicates-in-a-vector-of-strings)

if you cannot I suggest to use additional `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`:

```
std::set<std::pair<int, bool>> tset;
int lastValue = 0;
for (auto it = container.cbegin(); it != container.cend();)
{
    if( it->first != lastValue ) {
        tset.clear();
        lastValue = it->first;
    }

    if( !tset.insert( it->second ).second )
        it = container.erase( it );
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Comment: right, completely forgot about the sorted part. Thank you sir

Comment: I cannot change my data type to: std::map<int, std::vector<std::pair<int, bool>>> So this is why I ask the question. I will try. Thanks!